# Exclude from Refresh but Still Getting Error - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI Report which contains a data flow which is automatically refreshed each morning, and a static excel which contains daily production targets.
The excel file is in a folder on a shared drive, for which I had set up a personal gateway in order to refresh. However, if I am not online the gateway is of course not active.

To try to circumvent this issue, I chose to exclude the excel file from refresh in power query editor. However, when the automatic refresh occurs each morning, I am still getting an error message that the report has failed to refresh as my personal gateway was not line.

Is there another way to avoid this issue?

Comment: Is the Power BI report on a server ? And the 'gateway' on your personal computer ? What is it exactly ? Could you ask your admin to get a service account so the report on the server can access the excel file in the sharedfolder directly ?

Comment: You can remove the Gateway from your PBI Service. This should solve your issue.